# How to use the residual of FMOLS when conducting VECM in Stata

Tags: stata, vector-error-correction-model, granger-causality

I am trying to figure out whether the results of FMOLS (cointreg command in Stata) has uni-directional or bi-directional Granger causality relationship. I have seen people do this in Eviews but not in Stata.

How can I use the residuals of FMOLS as the ECT in VECM in Stata?